# How to draw a list of paths on a canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-controls

In my WPF **MVVM** application I have a `ListBox` with `Canvas` as its `ItemsPanel`. The ListBox's items are dynamically created by the user when he clicks a button - the `ListBox.ItemsSource` is a list of `Elements` (custom type) stored in my `MainViewModel`, which is the `DataContext` of my `MainWindow`.

Currently my `Element` class describes simple objects with X and Y coordinates (so that it could be drawn on the Canvas of my ListBox) and some data called `ShapeGeometry` to be drawn as a path. This is its `DataTemplate`:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localvm:Element}">
    <Control IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">
        <Control.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"> <!-- Paths need to be wrapped in a Canvas + Viewbox to be movable, stretchable and rotatable -->
                    <Canvas>
                        <Path x:Name="Path" Fill="#FFAA0000" Data="{Binding ShapeGeometry}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Path" Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>                                    
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Control.Template>
    </Control>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see, this allows me to draw only one specific Path per ListBoxItem. Instead, I'd like my ListBoxItem to be a `ComplexElement` containing a list of `Element` items, which means the drawn item would now consist of a various number of Paths. Now, my idea on how to achieve this would be to define `ListBoxItem` as `ListBox` with `ViewBox` + `Canvas` as its `ItemsPanel`, just as it is on the upper level, but it seems overly complicated and could perhaps prove to be a little inefficient (I intend to have tens if not a few hundreds of items). Is there a simpler way around it? Can I somehow avoid having ListBoxes in every `ListBoxItem`?

Comment: The `ShapeGeometry` (which the Path's `Data` is bound to) could be a `GeometryGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce overhead and have one list, you should be able to swap out the ListBox with a DataGrid control.

Then add the Canvas to your [RowDetailsTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Or you can put a second ListBox in the RowDetailsTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use a customized control (which has a ListBox or anything you want) as the DataTemplate for ListBox.ItemTemplate.In that way,you can reduce the complexity of the ListBox and the cutomized control may meet your needs by implementing your own logic.

### 1.Define the control class

```
public class MyListItem : Control
{
   //Define the property/event/control logic you want

   static MyListItem ()
   {
     //Remeber this to override the default style
     DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyListItem ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyListItem )));
   }
}
```

### 2.Define the Template

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:MyListItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:MyListItem}">
                <Border>
                   <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding YourDetailList}>
                      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                       //Anything you want here
                      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                   </ListBox>
                </Boder>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

### 3.Use it

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <my:MyListItem/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

### BTW

1.I do recommend you NOT use canvas as the ItemsPanel for the ListBox ,it may disable the the virtualizing which may reduce the performance when the ItemsSource is huge.

2.It seems that you want a nested ListBox，so if the ItemTemplate varies,you can use the 'ItemTemplateSelector',check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) .But remember the selector may be 'static' which means the datatemplate may be chosen only once in initialization.

3.Besides,if you want the Item changes its own behavior in some cases,try to use the Triggers in your Template or do it in the definition class.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. But the ItemsPanel must be a Canvas, because the small elements will need to appear potentially rotated and scaled at specific points (with the option to edit the "complex items" in a separate window after double-clicking on them). Unless you'd have a better idea.